# xslt transformation not working for wix installer window service

Tags: xslt, service, wix, window, installation

**

> I am using heat tool to dynamically generate window service out and
>   need to exclude exe file so I could add it manually.But it is not
>   working My step.build code is following

## **

```
<Target Name="Harvest">
     <!--Harvest all content of published result 
    Command="$(WixPath)heat dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MyWebWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode)"-->
    <Exec
        Command='"$(Wix)bin\heat" dir $(WindowServiceF) -t $(Projectdir)WixInstaller.xslt sfrag -o  -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MyWindowServiceComponents -var var.WindowServiceFDir -gg  -out $(WindowServiceGatCode)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
  </Target>
```

and transformation code is following

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="exe-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe')]" use="@Id"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('exe-search', @Id)]"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('exe-search', @Id)]"
```

**And code in my directoryref for window service is following**

```
<Component Id="WSComponent" Guid="608b5ac0-7541-4db8-9c79-6190ff437a83">
    <CreateFolder />
    <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
    <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />
    <File Id="WindowsServiceHost.exe" Source="$(var.TargitPath)GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe" KeyPath="yes"  Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
            Type="ownProcess"
            Vital="yes"
            Name="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost"                   
            DisplayName="WindowsService"
            Description="Wickedly awesome and amazing service."
            ErrorControl="ignore"
            Start="auto"
            Interactive="no" />

     <util:XmlFile Id="ModifyServiceLocation" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='DefaultConnection'[\]]/@connectionString" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe.config" Value="Data Source=PC4;Initial Catalog=dbGATAC;User Id=test;Password=ba"/>   
   <ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstaller"
               Start="install"
               Stop="both"
               Remove="both"
               Name="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost"
               Wait="yes" />
  </Component>

**But I get error failed to compare two elements in the error please check**
```

image for reference[image]